# What makes a structure-preserving map?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm trying to understand what is meant exactly by "structure-preserving map".  To do so, I'm looking at two examples I was given.  Note that I'm going to write everything in function notation because it helps illustrate what I'm saying better, I think.  So for instance, I'll write $\langle m_1, m_2\rangle$ as $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle(m_1,m_2)$.  Hopefully that won't confuse anyone.

First is a vector space $(M,+,\cdot)$ is a set $M$ along with two operations $+:M\times M\to M$ and $\cdot: \Bbb C\times M\to M$.  Then the structure-preserving maps on this are the functions $\phi: M\to N$ such that if $m_1, m_2\in M$ and $k\in\Bbb C$

$$\phi(+_M(m_1,m_2)) = +_N(\phi(m_1),\phi(m_2)) \\ \phi(\cdot_M(k,m_1)) = \cdot_N(k,\phi(m_1))$$

Seeing this I think structure-preserving maps are those maps that can commute (sorta) with the defining operations on the set.

Then I look at the notion of an inner product space $(M,+,\cdot,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$.  The structure-preserving maps on this space have the same properties as above -- because an IPS is a type of VS -- but additionally satisfies

$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle(\phi(m_1),\phi(m_2)) = \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle(m_1,m_2)$$

But this doesn't seem to fit with what I concluded about structure-preserving maps above.  I realize that something like $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle(\phi(m_1),\phi(m_2)) = \phi(\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle(m_1,m_2))$ wouldn't make sense because $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$'s target is the complex numbers, but then what makes this the additional condition for structure-preserving maps on IPS's?

If structure-preserving maps aren't the functions that sorta commute with the defining operations on the set, then how should I see them so that I can recognize what the structure-preserving maps must be when learning about new types of structures on sets?

Answer (score 2):

Consider metric spaces: there are tons of possible structure preserving maps between those: continuous maps, uniform maps, Lipschitz maps, isometries, Hölder continuous maps and so on and so forth. From a naive point there is no obvious "right" notion, although a structure preserving isomorphism should preserve properties you care about, like completeness (every Cauchy-sequence converges) in this example.

You probably need to decide for yourself why you care about a particular notion of structure preserving map if there is no obvious one.

---

Other than that: The "best" kind of structure preserving map gives you the "best" (category-theoretic) category. In the case of metric spaces $1$-Lipschitz maps seem to be better than everything else since the isomorphisms preserve e.g. completeness  and they make the category of metric spaces complete (that's a different kind of "complete"), unlike e.g. isometries. But these are sort of "high-level considerations".

Comment: So what you're saying is that when textbooks or Wikipedia says "the" structure-preserving maps they mean the maps that preserve the *most* structure possible (that have been discovered up to that point).  Then the definition of structure-preserving map for IPS's that I give above makes sense because the condition involving the IP says that $\phi$ preserves distance, in addition to addition and s-multiplication.

Comment: I'm saying it need not be completely obvious what the right kind of map needs to be.